# Angular 2 : Modal Toggle

Tags: forms, angular, modal-dialog, angular2-template, angular-forms

Why is it that when I click the edit button of a row, the modal unpredictably opens? Like -- few rows can be opened then the rest won't. Or when I try clicking those unopened rows, they can already be opened surprisingly. COMPLETELY UNPREDICTABLE.

Here are my codes:

> Section List:

```js
showDialogBox : boolean = false;

onToggleDialogBox(id) {
    this.showDialogBox = !this.showDialogBox;
    console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<table class="ui very basic table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="35%">Name</th>
            <th>Remarks</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let section of dataSource['docs']">
            <td><h4>{{section.name}}</h4></td>
            <td>{{section.remark}}</td>
            <td class="collapsing">
                <div class="ui small basic icon buttons">
                    <button class="ui button"><i class="write icon" (click)="onToggleDialogBox(section._id)"></i></button>
                    <button class="ui button"><i class="trash icon"></i></button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<app-dialog-form *ngIf="showDialogBox" [(showDialogBox)]="showDialogBox" #form>
    {{formTitle}}
    <div class="action" action>
        <button class="ui button basic" (click)="onToggleDialogBox()">Cancel</button>
        <button class="ui button primary medium" (click)="addSection(form.formValues)">Save</button>
    </div>
</app-dialog-form>
```

> Dialog Form:
>
> ***(I don't think there's no need for the HTML because I just want to know why the showing of modal is unpredictable upon clicking the edit icon/button above)***

```js
@Input() showDialogBox : boolean = true;
@Output() showDialogBoxChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

Comment: Try replacing toggle with open-close methods, with toggles there are issues with doubleclick or opening-closing time spans. The issue you have is because you bind the boolean  and maybe not only your openDialog method changes it but also the app-dialog-form does

Comment: I tried specifying the actions. I had different methods for closing and opening the modal but it still has the same issue. @nrgjack